# Opencart SEO URL Not working

Tags: opencart

I'm stuck in this from last 2 days I have no idea now what to do I have google it all over but I didn't find any thing workable.

So the problem is I'm working on Ecommerce Website which is on server now I just want to enable SEO URL in Admin Panel --> System --> Setting --> Server --> there is a radio button when I check on YES and click on save button it shows me error of 403 Forbidden,
I mean I done each and every thing I have changed .htaccess.txt file to .htaccess I have enabled my rewrite_mode but still get this error...

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please, read these links to improve your question: [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) | [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) | [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Is it Nginx server?

Answer (score 0):

from host in public_html directory rename .htaccess.txt to .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

In .htaccess file comment out
RewriteBase / (line no. 24) to

#### # RewriteBase /